# How do you disable expanding of ReactTable Pivot cell with only one child?

Tags: reactjs

I am using React and specifically [ReactTable](https://react-table.js.org/#/story/readme) to build a simple UI for managing a couple database tables.  Currently I have two Pivot columns, and overall things work well but I was hoping to make rows (especially for the second pivot) that only have one child not be expanding rows (since there is no need to expand to see all the data in that case) but still be able to expand those entries that do have more than one child. I see that I can customize the PivotValue and Expander but the values for those keys seem to be under the element that provides the expansion function. Is it possible to either conditionally enable expansion or control the element at the level of the expansion so that single rows don't expand?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
Here you go:
https://codesandbox.io/s/z2v5p0w6rp

I have added some additional stuff:

- Only expand when the pivot row has subrows
- Expander click works on the whole row
- Separated expander column on the left